# Change an image when the screen is resized

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to use  in laravel. I hope the image inside the tag changes when the screen becomes 365px, I need the images that use the  tag to have to keep some styles.

Originally my code has:

```
<img class="bigger" src="{{ URL::asset('Assets/Portal/images/Slide.png') }}" style="width: 100%;"/>
    @if($Permises['s_1'] == 1)
    <div class="contain" style="width: 100%;    margin-top: -5%; display: flexbox; border:none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
            <div class="element element1">
                <a href="{{ URL::to('/Review')}}" id="Main" style="color:transparent;">
                    <img class="d1" height="150" src="{{ URL::asset('Assets/Portal/images/IndexImg/D.png') }}" style="margin-top:0px;  opacity: .5;" width="150">
                    </img>
                </a>
            </div>
            @if($Cpermises['V_B'] == 1)
            <div class="element element2">
                <a href="{{ URL::to('/Bordereau')}}" id="Page1" style="color:transparent;">
                    <img class="d1" height="150" src="{{ URL::asset('Assets/Portal/images/IndexImg/A.png') }}" style="margin-top:0px; opacity: .5;" width="150">
                    </img>
                </a>
            </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    @else
```

When I want to use `<picture>`  the image doesn't even appear.

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-flow: row; justify-content: center; background-color: green; width: 100%; height: 100vh;">
    <div class="element element2">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width: 965px)" srcset="{{ URL::asset('Assets/Portal/images/responsive/sm/D.png') }}">
            <source media="(max-width: 365px)" srcset="{{ URL::asset('Assets/Portal/images/responsive/sm/D.png') }}" style="border: none; ">
            <img class="d1" height="150" src="{{ URL::asset('Assets/Portal/images/IndexImg/A.png') }}" style="margin-top:0px;  opacity: .5;" width="150"/>
        </picture>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an example of the result I want.

[Click this to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffaG8.png)

Comment: Laravel is a PHP framework, has  little to do with CSS rules.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use media queries in your css.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 365px) and (max-width: 965px) {
  .d1 {
    background-image: url('Assets/Portal/images/responsive/sm/A.png')
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 965px) {
  .d1 {
    background-image: url('Assets/Portal/images/responsive/sm/B.png')
  }
}
```